# How do I achieve higher resolution than physical resolution of an LCD?

Tags: xorg, compiz, resolution

I'm using the original `EeePC` with screen resolution of `800x480`. Some screens and dialogs do not fit into that resolution, so I have to use `Alt-Drag` to move windows around to reveal the bottom part of the window, but this doesn't work for a particular application I'm going to use since it's basically a fullscreen DirectX app running via wine, so some buttons are just cut off by the edge of the screen.

Is there a way to make `Xorg` desktop to render at higher resolution (`1024px` wide or so) and then transparently scaled down to the display's native resolution, so the applications think the resolution is bigger? I do not care much about output getting blurred or text getting too small.

Alternatively, is there a way to switch the video adapter to the resolution above physical resolution of the LCD screen and have the screen/video adapter itself to handle scaling (as used to be possible with CRT monitors)?

I'm using **Lubuntu 12.04** so I guess have `Compiz` installed. There is Scale plugin in `Compiz`, but I don't think it does what I need.

Comment: KDE has a way of zooming out... that does something like what you're describing. Though generally you don't do much more than select windows at that level. But I'd say it's possible.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In short, you want something like

```
xrandr --output LVDS --scale 1.28x1.28
```

(replacing `LVDS` with the desired output name, as seen in the output of running `xrandr` by itself).

Give it a try.  Some sites said that this doesn't work on some systems that are using KMS (kernel mode setting); if so, that's a bug that's hopefully fixed.  See these links for some more info on using `xrandr` to scale a screen like this:

- [Increase (scale) LCD resolution under Ubuntu](http://forum.eeeuser.com/index.php?/topic/76839-increase-scale-lcd-resolution-under-ubuntu/)
- [Having a bigger resolution than the native one?](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=75534)
- [Fun with xrandr and tiny Netbook screens :)](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/20634/fun-with-xrandr-and-tiny-netbook-screens/)

Comment: Awesome, I'll try that and report back

Comment: Setting the screen size worked fine, however, mouse cursor is limited to the previous screen size - I can not move the cursor outside of the invisible 800x480 rectangle. Do you know what might be causing it? If I won't find a solution I guess I'll ask a separate answer.

Comment: Sounds like a known bug: see e.g. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/883319 and https://www.google.com/search?q=xrandr+scale+mouse+limited.  There may be a solution in one of those, I haven't looked.

Comment: According to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/883319/comments/62, the mouse-limiting bug has been fixed in Ubuntu 12.10 although it is now also necessary to specify `--panning` parameter in the command.

Comment: nice, but doesnt work with my Nvidia. had to use intern intel graphics instead (via nvidia-settings)

Answer (score 3):

Go here and download "newrez"

http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/newrez+-+Increase+Screen+Rez+For+Netbook?content=134686

I'm the author.  It overcomes the trapped mouse problem.

Comment: Would you mind adding some more details about newrez? Just to make this answer more canonical than just a link.