# HiDPI scaling for non-aware applications

Tags: xorg

### Current situation

I have a 15" 3200x1800 screen, which is referred to as Retina or HiDPI. Using Linux Mint Cinnamon, I already have a desktop that scales nicely - but that's pretty much it. Besides Firefox proprietary setting for HiDPI screens, other applications usually only have fonts scaled, without window layouts taking that into account.

### Question

Is it (and how) possible, to have application specific scaling for their windows?

### Possible solution

I am no expert on X, multiple displays or tunneling, but: Maybe this is possible through the use of a second xserver running that has this solution applied: [Can X11 scale to virtual resoltions on HiDPI/Retina screens the way OS X does?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69104/can-x11-scale-to-virtual-resoltions-on-hidpi-retina-screens-the-way-os-x-does) and somehow the resulting windows are being tunneled to the main screen? If that was possible, one could write a wrapper so non hidpi applications do not kill the user's eyes.

Answer (score 2):

The following could provide a temporary solution.

https://github.com/rubo77/set_resolution.py

List the applications you wish to scale and the resolution you wish to scale them to. There is a second or so lag when switching applications, but it's the best I've got until developers start accommodating HiDPi screens by default.